# Using regex how do I stop identifiers matching strings

Tags: regex, lexer

Let's say I have this "code" I want to lex.

```
var text = 'hello'
```

Here's my regex.

- String: ([a-z\s]+)
- Identifier: [a-z]+

Now when I put my code into regexr.com and use the identifier regex, it matches the string as an identifier, how would I stop it from matching strings as identifiers?

Answer (score 1):

What identifies a string? Quotation marks. In your case: single quotes.

Therefore, we want to match the content between quotes as a string. To do so, we can use the following lazy regex:

```
'.*?'
```

To allow both quotes, you could use: `'.*?'|".*?"` or the same with a backreference `(['"]).*?\1`.

If it is allowed to escape strings, it gets even more complicated. I suggest using a recursive regex to do so:

```
((['"])(?>[^'"\\]++|\\.|(?1))*+\2)
```

[Samples matched](https://regex101.com/r/iMROBQ/1):

```
a = "abc   dsfsd", b= ' abc   dsfsd'
c ="abc\"   dsfsd"
d= "abc\\"
```

---

To match any identifiers but the strings you could use:

```
[a-z]+(?=([^']*['][^']*['])*[^']*$)
```

(Or here a version that matches both types of quotes: `[a-z]+(?=([^'"]*(["'])[^"']*\2)*[^"']*$)`)

Again, it gets more involved if you want to account for escaped quotes:

```
[a-z]+(?=([^"'\\]*(\\.|(["'])([^"'\\]*\\.)*[^"'\\]*\3))*[^"']*$)
```

I hope, this helps.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm trying to stop the identifier regex from matching a string.

Comment: Not a problem. Updated.